# How do I define robot thin-100 style using serif

Tags: android, android-layout, fonts, roboto

I want to achieve the [robot thin-100 font](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Roboto) using serif. But so far my attempts are not successful. Any help?

```
<style name="text_style" tools:targetApi="16">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-thin</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#333333</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Did you try to download and use them as regular TTF fonts?

Comment: By "them" do you mean roboto? No, I am trying to avoid downloading Roboto since supposedly I should be able to accomplish Roboto with san-serif et al.

Comment: It helps if you say whether your apk compiles, and what you're testing it on, and whether you checked that device actually *has* roboto.